# C# How to select an object on a listbox from another listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Say I want `listBox1` to contain a set of first names. And when someone clicks on one of those first names, it will display the last name in `listBox2` and **already selected**.

I seem to not be able to have the second listbox have it already selected.

So if the first item in `listBox1` is selected, the first item in `listBox2` is selected. And so on.

How would such be possible?

Here is some code:

```
private void materialFlatButton3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "DLL Files|*.dll";
            OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Dll File";
            if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // put the selected result in the global variable
                fullFileName = new List<String>(OpenFileDialog1.FileNames);


                foreach (string s in OpenFileDialog1.FileNames)
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(s));
                    listBox4.Items.Add(s);
                }

            }
        }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem);
        textBox3.Text = text;
    }
```

In listbox4, it displays the full path. In listbox2, it displays just the name of the file.

How would I make it so when someone clicks on a file in listbox2, its corresponding path will be selected in listbox4?

Comment: Use `DataGridView` with two columns `Name` and `Full path`

Comment: @Fabio I want my users to only see the name, not the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create you own type for storing and displaying the file names:

```
public class FileItem
{
    public FileItem (string path) => FullPath = path;
    public string FullPath { get; }
    public override ToString() => Path.GetFileName(FullPath);
}
```

And add these items to the listbox. That way you can store the full path and display the file name at the same time.

---

Alternatively just keep a reference to the original Files array or copy its content to another array. Then get the full path from this array through the selected index instead of from a second listbox ony used to store things.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class which represent full path and name for displaying.
Then use bind loaded data to the `ListBox`

```
public class MyPath
{
    public string FullPath { get; private set; }
    public string Name '
    { 
        get { return Path.GetFileName(s) }             
    }

    public MyPath(string path)
    {
        FullPath = path;
    }
}

// Load and bind it to the ListBox

var data = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
                            .Select(path => new MyPath(path))
                            .ToList();

// Name of the property which will be used for displaying text
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"; 
listBox1.DataSource = data;

private void ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedPath = (MyPath)ListBox1.SelectedItem;
    // Both name and full path can be accesses without second listbox
    // selectedPath.FullPath
    // selectedPath.Name
}
```